# Auto order column values in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, ssms

I have a very simple table:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| StatusID |             StatusName              |        Description         |
+----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|        1 | Created                             |Something has been Created  |
|        3 | Updated                             |Something has been Updated  |
|        7 | Deleted                             |Something has been Deleted  | 
|       10 | Purged                              |Something has been Purged   | 
|        2 | Canceled                            |Something has been Cancelled|
+----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I am inserting different StatusIDs, but they are not orderred on insert. I am familiar with the ORDER BY statement in SQL, but I would like to know if there is an auto ORDER option is SQL management studio? So that when I click on my table and Select top X records I get a sorted view automatically?

Comment: Create a view and add desired order by in the view.

Comment: @ShijuShaji  Adding ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified

Comment: Most times the tables in a relational DB have clustered index as the primary key and that is usually the order in which the records are retrieved unless there is some fragmentation. Lets be clear here, the only way to get a guaranteed order is by explicitly adding an order by clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't and don't depend on actual physical ordering of data in disk. If you need a specific order of data to display then use `order by` clause with a sort direction `ASC / DESC` and that's the sole purpose of `ORDER BY`.